# Subset sum with number reuse allowed

Tags: javascript, math, subset, subset-sum

I have a list of positive integers e.g. `15, 29, 110`, and a target e.g. `44`. I'm trying to find all possible combinations which sum to the target but importantly, the numbers in the set can be used multiple times e.g.

```
Target = 44
Result = 1x15, 1x29

Target = 307
Result = 2x110, 3x29
```

I found a dynamic programming solution which works when the combination is no more than one of each number. So Target 44 works but not my 307 example (returns Not Found).

How can the multiples or number reuse be done?

```
function subset(people, min, max)
{
  var subsets = [];
  subsets[0] = '';

  for (var person in people)
  {
    for (var s = min-1; s >= 0; --s)
    {
      if (s in subsets)
      {
        var sum = s + people[person];

        if (!(sum in subsets))
        {
          subsets[sum] = subsets[s] + ' ' + person;

          if (sum >= min && sum <= max)
          {
            return subsets[sum];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 'Not found';
}

var p = {
   optionA:15,
   optionB:29,
   optionC:110
};
var qty = 307;
console.log(subset(p, qty, qty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive solution:

```js
function subset(people, min, max) {
 const pairs = Object.entries(people),
  results = [],
  getSum = multiplications => multiplications.reduce((sum, multiplicator, position) => 
   sum + pairs[position][1] * multiplicator, 0),
  formatResult = result => result.map(multiplications => 
   multiplications.reduce((res, multiplicator, position) => 
   (multiplicator > 0 ? res.push(`${multiplicator}x${pairs[position][1]}`) : 
    res, res), []));
 function findSums(multiplications, position) {
  let s;
  while((s = getSum(multiplications)) <= max) {
   if (s >= min) {
    results.push([...multiplications]);
   }
   if (position < pairs.length - 1) {
    const m = [...multiplications],
     nextPosition = position + 1;
    m[nextPosition]++;
    findSums(m, nextPosition);
   }
   multiplications[position]++;
  }
 }
 findSums(pairs.map(_ => 0), 0);
 return results.length > 0 ? formatResult(results) : "Not found";
}

var p = {
   optionA:15,
   optionB:29,
   optionC:110
};
var qty = 307;
console.log(subset(p, qty, qty));
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for most tests I've tried but it misses a solution in the following example: target is 650, options are 50, 225, 550. It doesn't find the solution of 1x550, 2x50. `subset({optionA:50, optionB:225, optionC:550}, 650, 650)`. Is it possible to correct for this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the second loop in such way:

```
for (var s = 0; s <= wantedSum - people[person] ; s++)
```

Using this approach you fill all entries of `subsets[]` array\list where index is multiple of `people[person]` (instead of single entry). For example, with value 3 you fill 3,6,9,12... entries.